# Trying to copy a string into a struct aray

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I am trying to copy a string into my struct array. I get the following error message:

> error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '.' token

for the bold line. I tried different variants but without success.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Album {
    char Interpret[20];
    char Titel[10];
    int Jahr;
    int Zustand;
} album;

album regal[2];

strcpy(char *regal[0].Interpret, "Led Zeppelin");  // here

int main() {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Get rid of `char *` in the function call.

Comment: @Eraklon thanks very much, i am sorry for posting that stupid mistake :/

Comment: You should consider to add the track titles by an array of strings into the structure `album`. Without that it can ruin your whole concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attempting to run a statement (a function call in this case) outside of a function.  It should be moved inside `main`:

```
int main ()
{  
    strcpy(regal[0].Interpret, "Led Zeppelin");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the file scope you may place only declarations. You may not use statements.

Also there is no need to define the array as global. And the call of the function `strcpy` is incorrect. The function main can look like

```
int main() 
{
    album regal[2];

    strcpy(regal[0].Interpret, "Led Zeppelin");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note that it is also possible to use initialization syntax for `regal`, instead of declaring it uninitialized and then filling out the fields

Answer (score 0):

strcpy() is a function from "string" library.

You can't call functions in the global scope of a file. It must have a scope that relates to the one of the main() function of your program (as in, if you go up in the call stack, you end up in your main() function), or to the scope of a constructor of a class/struct of which you create a static object.

But you can assign values or execute statement in global scope.

Answer (score 0):

Line **strcpy(char *regal[0].Interpret, "Led Zeppelin");  // here*** needs to be inside main. also regal is already defined so you don't need char in strcpy function.

Answer (score -2):

```
Can't define struct outside of function, define in main, should look like:

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Album {
    char Interpret[20];
    char Titel[10];
    int Jahr;
    int Zustand;
} album;


int main() {
album regal[2];

strcpy(char *regal[0].Interpret, "Led Zeppelin"); 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Don't answer your own question - unless there is no other acceptable answer. Mark the other answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to it.